# Nullable types in generic class

Tags: c#, generics, null

I need to create a class similar to this:

```
class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T[] Arr {get; }
    public GenericClass(int n)
    {
        Arr = new T[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Arr[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But there is a compiler error:

> **CS0403** Cannot convert null to type parameter 'T' because it could be a non-nullable value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead.

I don't want to use `default(T)`, because it could be the same as normal value but I need to distinguish. I don't know the type so I can't use minimal value. How can I use null?

Comment: That's because at compile time the compiler doesn't know what is T going to be (class or struct)

Comment: You can't just use null at that level of generic-ness, that's the thing. What if you wanted T to be an int (regular, non-nullable)? You can't assign an int null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are actually shooting yourself in the foot here. Arrays in .NET are automatically set to the default value of the type, so as long as a type's default is null (all objects and nullables), then simply creating the array is enough to set all items to null. Without that excess code, you may never have encountered an issue at all, depending on how you're trying to use this class.

If you're trying to allow cases like `GenericClass<int>` and have it expose an array of `int?`s, then do this. The `where T : struct` enforces that the supplied type is a value type, thereby allowing you to use `T?`. You can't use object types for the generic parameter in this case.

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : struct
{
    public T?[] Arr { get; }
    public GenericClass(int n)
    {
        Arr = new T?[n];
    }
}
```

If you're trying to create a class that supports both object instances and nullables, try this. The problem here is you can't make a type constraint -- if you use `where T : struct`, you can't use object types; and if you use `where T : class`, you can't use nullables. Therefore, this type allows usages like `GenericClass<MyObject>` (works like you want), `GenericClass<int?>` (works like you want) and `GenericClass<int>` (doesn't work like you want, and can't possibly work like you want anyway). Unfortunately, there's no way to define this generic to disallow the latter case. You can make that check at runtime if you like, though.

```
class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T[] Arr { get; }
    public GenericClass(int n)
    {
        Arr = new T[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, very occasionally I will find a situation where I do need to do something like what OP is talking about -- converting a `null` literal to a `T` generic. In these cases, I have used a double-cast -- `(T) (object) null`. You should almost never have to do this, though.

Answer (score 11):

The thing with generics is that they have to consider the possibility of `T` being literally anything, including a type that cannot be `null` (value types including primitives and structs). In order to restrict the generic parameter to types that *can* be `null`, you need to add the `class` restraint:

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : class
{
    public T[] Arr { get; private set; }
    public GenericClass(int n)
    {
        Arr = new T[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Arr[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may not want to be dealing with `null` at all. Instead, you can replace

```
Arr[i] = null;
```

with

```
Arr[i] = default(T);
```

and it will work fine. `default(T)` will return `null` for any nullable type and the default value for any non-nullable type. (0 for `int`, false for `bool`, etc.)

**EDIT:** As another alternative, you can represent the object internally with a `Nullable` wrapper type. C# allows a shorthand for this syntax with the `?` operator:

```
class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T?[] Arr { get; private set; }
    public GenericClass(int n)
    {
        Arr = new T?[n];
    }
}
```

Incidentally, with this approach, there's no need to iterate over every index of the array and set it to `null`, as C# will handle that for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you know that `T` *must be* a nullable type, say, `Nullable<Xyz>`, you can force your users to pass `Xyz` instead, and make `Nullable<Xyz>` (aka `Xyz?`) internally:

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : struct {
    public T?[] Arr {get; }
    public GenericClass(int n) {
        Arr = new T?[n]; // This will create an array of nulls, no need for a loop
    }
}
```

The `where T : struct` constraint added to the declaration will prevent `GenericClass<T>` instantiations with arguments that are *not* value types. For example, an attempt to make `GenericType<string>` will result in compile-time error.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is instantiate your class with a nullable type if it's a value type:

```
var obj = new GenericClass<int?>();
```

Then you can use `default(T)` instead of null without issue. You'll just end up with an `int?[]` array though you don't need to use it explicitly because each element in the array will automatically get the default value when the array is instantiated.