Problem with generic class with a nullable attribute
I have this C# code:
using System;

namespace NullableExample
{
    public class PAttribute<T>
    {
        public T? Value { get; set; }

        public bool IsPertinent { get; set; }

        // Public parameterless constructor is required for serialization
        public PAttribute() { 
            IsPertinent = true;
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        private PAttribute<bool> testAttribute = new PAttribute<bool>();

        public void SetValue()
        {
            testAttribute.Value = (bool?)true; // gives compilation error
            testAttribute.Value = true;
            testAttribute.Value = null; // gives compilation error
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            myClass.SetValue();
        }
    }
}


I need to assign a bool? to testAttribute.Value, but the compiler seems to think it's a bool.
My csproject is this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Any help would be appreciated!
I tried to compile the code but got a compilation error:

\csharp\TestBool\Program.cs(24,74): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

However in my real project I cannot do this explicit conversion.

See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117642/nullable-types-in-generic-class. What is T going to be? If you want it to be generic, see this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627384/generic-class-using-nullable-property-of-generic-type

For value types adding "where T : struct" seems to work. But it has to work also for reference types. There you have to  add "where T : class". So you would need a PValueAttribute and a PReferenceAttribute. My actual question is if it is possible to combine that so that you only need one class PAttribute.
